# Java Selenium Webdriver Sendkeys input Variable AND Keys at the same time

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to know how could we input a variable and some keys in only one sendkeys method. In fact in a textfield, I want to input "Ctrl+A" to select the current value, and replace it with a new value which is stocked in a varialbe called "orderNumber".

For example :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@class='nodrag nodrop filter row_hover']/th[@class='text-center'
[2]/input[@class='filter']")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"a");
```

Then

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@class='nodrag nodrop filter row_hover']/th[@class='text-center'
[2]/input[@class='filter']")).sendKeys(orderNumber);
```

Is there a way to combine these 2 lines into 1 line? I tried this it doesn't work.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@class='nodrag nodrop filter row_hover']/th[@class='text-center'
[2]/input[@class='filter']")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"a" , orderNumber);
```

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: http://artoftesting.com/automationTesting/handling-keyboard-events-in-selenium.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver: I want to overwrite value in field instead of appending to it with sendKeys using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249583/selenium-webdriver-i-want-to-overwrite-value-in-field-instead-of-appending-to-i)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that, you could use the `clear()` function in the textfield web element.

So, for example:

```
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/");

        WebElement el =driver.findElement(By.className("gsfi"));
        el.sendKeys("hello!");

        el.clear();

        int orderNumber=1;

        el.sendKeys(String.valueOf(orderNumber));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using following code,

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@class='nodrag nodrop filter row_hover']/th[@class='text-center'
[2]/input[@class='filter']"));
ele.clear();
ele.sendkeys(orderNumber);
```